# I removed Messaging

Tags: tiles, pin-to-start

So, I removed the "Messaging" tile from the Start screen and now it can't be pinned back. Any advice?

What I've tried so far is removing more tiles thinking it needed more space, but no luck.

Comment: Have you rebooted the phone? I've noticed that solved the problem when I couldn't pin tiles before.

Comment: What happens when you go to the `Messaging` in  the application list and tap and hold?

Answer (score 4):

Just go to app list, hold **Messaging** app and tap **pin to start**.

Answer (score -1):

Ah just worked it out. It just gets shoved back on the start screen some where else.